# Access internal regs without declaring them as input/outputs

Tags: verilog, hierarchy

How do I access internal regs/signals without declaring them as input/output.
e.g., consider the following block, A & B are placed in TOP block and I need to access int_A from withing block B without declaring it as output in A and input in B.

[image]

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no way (and I would be actually shocked if there is one, as it would mean that "sideeffects" could be implemented which implies serious testablity issues). Could you elaborate why "exposing" int_T is not an option for you?

Comment: Well, I am creating a block which has both digital and analog blocks. in order to model the analog block i need to create element which do not really exist in the analog.
e.g. say the analog block has an output voltage output. This output it a 'single bit' from the analog part. However inside the analog block MODEL I use a 'real' or bus to represent the voltage. i do not want to add extra outputs to the analog block, in this case the representation of the voltage.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by hierarchical reference.
However as far as I know you can only use that in test-benches.(I have never even **dared** to use that in RTL).

```
// Top level test-bench

wire int_A;
   assign int_A = dut_0.int_A;

dut dut_0 ( // instance of dut
       .... 
       );
```

If inside the `dut` you have another instance use the same method:

```
module dut (
   );

  core core0 (
       ); 
endmodule // dut
```

A signal inside the core can now be referenced from the top level as:

assign int_A = dut_0.core_0.int_A;

Comment: so the way to do this, in my case, since A & B are under the TOP, is to use 2 statements?
1 in the top to reference the wire in Block A, and 1 in block B to reference the wire (reference) in A?

Is there a way to use only 1 definition, inside block B which references a wire in A?
Both A & B are under TOP.

Comment: I think you can do a full path reference form anywhere in the design. Thus in B you can use  `top.A.int_A`.